# Decrypt function can't read content hash throws : TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:

Tags: javascript, node.js, aes, cryptojs

When I first tested it both the encrypt and decrypt using the aes-256-ctr algorithm worked fine but after I posted it to IPFS and returned it it gave me the following error.

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined

It all looks up to par for me.
Here is the encryption.js file.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
const secretKey = 'vOH6sdmpNWjRRIqCc7rdxs01lwHzfr33';
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
//const file = fs.readFileSync("test.txt");
//console.log(secretKey.length);
const encrypt = (text) => {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv);
  const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()]);
  return {
    iv: iv.toString('hex'),
    content: encrypted.toString('hex')
  };
};
const decrypt = (hash) => {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, Buffer.from(hash.iv, 'hex'));
  const decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(Buffer.from(hash.content, 'hex')),
    decipher.final()]);
  return decrypted.toString();
};
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. Are you passing the entire object returned by encrypt into decrypt to get a decryption, or just the hash? You have to pass the whole object in, or else you get that error.

Comment: Great, I'll post that as the answer then.

Comment: please mark my answer as correct when you get the chance so the question gets marked as resolved :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work for me -- but only if you pass the entire object returned by `encrypt` into `decrypt`. If you just pass in the `hash` without the `iv`, you get that error.